# Which Eclipse Download?

Tags: eclipse

The [Eclipse downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) provides a selection of purpose oriented downloads.

I'm looking for the minimal download; I'll handpick the plugins I want.  Would I find this kind of 'core' download, or do I simply not grok eclipse yet.

Comment: Just as a note, mandatory thing before you start using Eclipse: disable spellchecking for code. Dumbest feature ever.

Comment: Seems that org.eclipse.platform is the only thing you really need;  http://www.eclipse.org/epp/content.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Eclipse Classic is what you're going for.  It's suited for basic Java development, but has a minimum of additional stuff.  I always start with that and then customize with the plugins I want.

Out of curiosity, what type of development are you doing?

Comment: "Classic" is a 170Mb download, yet the "C/C++" is 88 MB? Which is confusing. I'm mostly developing with python, php, html/js, sometimes coldfusion/java and now android/java; so a fairly eclectic mix. Have been using netbeans for the web stuff but considering a return for the java. The mercuial plugin on nb is a 'like'

Comment: Yeah, I don't pretend to understand the file sizes.  The Classic setup always seemed the most unassuming and malleable to me.  Can't speak to a lot of the other stuff you mentioned, but I love PyDev as a plugin for Python development. I've been maintaing a huge Java/Python code base using SVN for a long time and have been able to do it all via one customized Eclipse Classic setup.

Comment: the eclipse classic download is so big because it ships also the source code of the plataform

Answer (score 19):

I like to have a look at the "**[Compare Eclipse packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php)**" page first

That will explain the size difference between the "C/C++" package and the "Classic" Package.
The latter is suited for RCP (Rich Client Platform) development and **include the sources of Eclipse**.

If you want to do some classic Java development (and not some Eclipse plugin for Eclipse itself), you can start with the Java edition, and add plugins (like PDT for Php development) later.

[image]

Notice the orange ticks, which reference packages *with sources* included.

Comment: Slightly more extensive table here too:  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php.  I've looked at that downloads page a ton of times and never actually noticed that link.  Good to know  :-D

Comment: [Compare Eclipse packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php) link is dead.  The [Compare Packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) link works, but the page is named **Compare Eclipse Packages** so they probably replaced the old one.

Comment: @Trisped Thank you. I have updated the answer to reference only that link.

Comment: FYI: the page is actually called "Compare Eclipse Packages".  You took the title from the instructions on how to use the page. :)  You can get the actual title from the HTML or from the breadcrumb (purple bar).